# Snowfall Canvas, Change Particle Speed

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, html5-canvas

I'm trying to change the particle speed of this snowfall script but I can't seem to find the numbers that represent "Falling Speed". Right now the particles are falling too fast, here's the bulk of the script:

```
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
            var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

            var container;

            var particle;

            var camera;
            var scene;
            var renderer;

            var mouseX = 0;
            var mouseY = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            var particles = []; 
            var imgArr = new Array();


            function init() {

                container = document.createElement('div');
                document.body.appendChild(container);

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 1000;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

                for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    var particleImage = new Image();
                    particleImage.src = imgArr[Math.round(Math.random()*(imgArr.length-1))];
                    var material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.Texture(particleImage) } );
                    particle = new Particle3D( material);
                    particle.position.x = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                    particle.position.y = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                    particle.position.z = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                    particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y =  0.8;
                    scene.add( particle );

                    particles.push(particle); 
                }

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                setInterval( loop, 1000 / 60 );

            }

            function loop() {

            for(var i = 0; i<particles.length; i++)
                {

                    var particle = particles[i]; 
                    particle.updatePhysics(); 

                    with(particle.position)
                    {
                        if(y<-1000) y+=2000; 
                        if(x>1000) x-=2000; 
                        else if(x<-1000) x+=2000; 
                        if(z>1000) z-=2000; 
                        else if(z<-1000) z+=2000; 
                    }               
                }

                renderer.render( scene, camera );


            }
```

It's using Three.js as a backbone. Here's the original script to see it in action:

https://github.com/sebleedelisle/live-coding-presentations/tree/master/2011/JSSnow

Comment: In the `Particle3D` constructor in `Snow.js`, the particle initial velocity is set by `this.velocity = new THREE.Vector3( 0, -8, 0 );` You can change the -8 to -4 to decrease the particle speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the last line in the `init()` function:

```
setInterval( loop, 1000 / 60 );
```

The second argument of [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) sets the interval in milliseconds, after which the `loop()` function will be continuously called until you stops this with [clearInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp). I think this is what you are looking for.